# centering text in li inside of ul in a div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

hi i want to my text be in the center of the li inside of the ul in a div 
but no matter what do i do i can't get it fixed

i can't find the problem

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initil-scall=1.0">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="qw" class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">خانه</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">خدمات</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">درباره ما</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">تماس با ما</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">اموزش ها</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and  this is my css code

```
body {
    background: url("images (1).jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoder(src='images.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}

header nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    border-bottom: #9f4f89;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: #d39fb7;
}
header nav #qw {
    background: transparent url("") no-repeat left 5px;
}

header nav #qw ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav #qw li {
    height: 2em;
    float: right;
    padding: auto;

}

header nav #qw ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;

}

header nav #qw ul li a {
    padding: 32px 32px 7px 7px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

with this code the text are in the left bottom of the elements but i want them to be in the center of the element

Comment: remove` float:right` from `li` tag

Answer (score 0):

Remove`float:right` from `li` tag and add `display:inline-block` in `a` tag

```css
body {
    background: url("images (1).jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoder(src='images.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}

header nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    border-bottom: #9f4f89;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: #d39fb7;
}
header nav #qw {
    background: transparent url("") no-repeat left 5px;
}

header nav #qw ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav #qw li {
    height: 2em;
    padding: auto;

}

header nav #qw ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav #qw ul li a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="qw" class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">خانه</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">خدمات</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">درباره ما</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">تماس با ما</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">اموزش ها</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding you've set up for your links:

```
header nav #qw ul li a {
padding: 32px 32px 7px 7px;
/* everything else that's already wrriten */
}
```

is causing the problem, since *the order of the padding setting goes*:

```
padding: top right bottom left;
```

so to properly center the text inside of the li, you should change the padding to:

```
header nav #qw ul li a {
padding: 32px 32px 7px 32px; 
/* everything else that's already wrriten */
}
```

or, if you wanted the top and bottom padding to be the same, and the left and right padding to be the same, then:

```
header nav #qw ul li a {
padding: 7px 32px 7px 32px;
/* everything else that's already wrriten */
}
```

This would fix your problem.

*P.S. you could also remove `float: right;` from:*

```
header nav #qw ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: right; /* <- this part is not needed. */
}
```